Issue on Deploying an Enhanced LWR Site for B2B Commerce - DigitalExperienceBundle
We are looking to validate and deploy B2B Commerce Site. On validation we receive the error: [DigitalExperienceBundle site/NAMEOFTHECOMMUNITY] An unexpected error occurred.
Salesforce support specified that on their end the error message is as follows: 'The folder is an invalid location for this content. Move the content to the _settings folder'.
We have already tried moving all the content of digitalExperiences/site/NAMEOFTHECOMMUNITY to a manually created '_settings' folder and we got an error for every file: e.g. DigitalExperienceBundle/ site/NAMEOFTHECOMMUNITY/_settings/sfdc_cms_route/Current_Checkout/_metal The content apiName included in the member name sfdc_cms_route is invalid. Use only alphanumeric or underscore characters and begin the content apiName with a letter'
We are Using Enhanced LWR Site, therefore including DigitalExperience metadata, rather than experience, as per the below documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm
Any ideas on a resolution to  this?

Seems to me that Support should be telling you what this really means. I doubt it is that everything needs to be moved, more that some part of the metadata within the bundle is in the wrong folder.

Have you checked if this is deployable to a scratch org using the CLI?
Did you change the API version for your project recently?

Consider that Salesforce does restructure bundle content every now and again and that the API version may need to be set to an earlier version from before some metadata restructuring done by Salesforce.
